# Performance testing - multiple websocket connections

Tags: html, websocket, jmeter, performance-testing

I would need to test the "resistance" of the server receiving an increasing number of websocket connections, through which data is sent over MQTT.
To that purpose, I created a simple webpage which has an "onLoad" directive so that when it loads, it connects to the server over websocket and starts receiving the data. In order to simulate (and increase the number of websocket connections), I thought about JMeter with a Loop controller that opens the page. However, I note that when the page is loaded by JMeter, it does not establish the websocket (in other words, it discards the "onLoad") javascript directive in the page. Is there a special JMeter configuration I'm missing? Is there another way to achieved what I would like?
Many thanks - Christian

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMeter project main page](https://jmeter.apache.org/):

> JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. **In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages.** Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

therefore your [onload event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp) is being absolutely ignored by JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler as it doesn't execute any functions.

If you want to load test your websocket backend you will need to go for [JMeter WebSocket Samplers](https://github.com/ptrd/jmeter-websocket-samplers) and establish connection/send payload using the relevant samplers. The plugin can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/), there are [JMeter WebSocket Samplers - A Practical Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-websocket-samplers-a-practical-guide) article and [some example JMeter scripts](https://github.com/ptrd/jmeter-websocket-samplers/tree/master/samples) which you can use as the reference

Comment: Thanks very much - it is clear. I used the websocket sampler but the reason why I wanted to go this extra step further is to not only test the opening of the connections but also keeping the connections up and sending traffic through whilst new connections are opening.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to it ? @Christian68